getPicklistValuesByRecordType returns networkAdapterError when used in a LWC in an offline mode with Graph QL and briefcase
We are invoking getPicklistValuesByRecordType to get the picklist values corresponding to default record type of Timesheet Entry in a lwc component in FSL app as shown below. When we run the LWC in the offline mode the below method returns error::{"errorType":"networkAdapterError"}
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: "TimeSheetEntry" })
    timeSheetEntryObjectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: "TimeSheetEntry", recordTypeId: "$timeSheetEntryObjectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId" })
    wiredDirectPicklistValues({ error, data }) {}

It is returning null when used with Graph QL adapters. If we invoke just this method in a separate component, it seems to be working. Does anyone has any idea why this might be happening, has it something to do with how we are priming the data?
Any help is greatly appreciated!
